# How to extract manipulated indexed variables from Manipulate

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, scoping, indexed-variable

I am struggling with getting values of variables that are manipulated with `Manipulate`:
The code:

```
plts = (mm[#]*Sin[x]) & /@ Range[5];
With[
 {localplot = plts /. {(mm[#] -> mv[#]) & /@ Range[5]} // Flatten},
 Manipulate[
  Plot[localplot, {x, 0, 10}],
  Evaluate[
   Sequence @@ ({{mv[#], 0, Subscript[a, #]}, 0, 1, 
        Appearance -> "Labeled"} & /@ Range[5])
   ],
  Button["Get values", data = Table[mv[i], {i, 1, 5}]; Print[data]]
  ]
```

returns

```
(* {mv[1],mv[2],mv[3],mv[4],mv[5]} *)
```

But if I change it to:

```
plts = (mm[#]*Sin[x]) & /@ Range[5];
With[
 {localplot = plts /. {(mm[#] -> mv[#]) & /@ Range[5]} // Flatten},
 Manipulate[
  Plot[localplot, {x, 0, 10}],
  Evaluate[
   Sequence @@ ({{mv[#], 0, Subscript[a, #]}, 0, 1, 
        Appearance -> "Labeled"} & /@ Range[5])
   ],
  Button["Get values", data = mv[3]; Print[data]]
  ]
 ]
```

It returns the correct values, why and how to get back values from indexed variables?

---

The above is MWE or MNWE. The full system is generated by the following code:

```
cdata = CloudGet[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/8df13783-4827-4fd1-be7b-65875d9b02ee"];
μd = {5422.6501499999995`, 6450.7998`, 6711.8498500000005`, 
   6824.2998`, 8795.4004`, 9502.0996`};
ad = {0.00267136`, 0.0210852`, 0.0228746`, 0.0311949`, 0.00351935`, 
   0.00333709`};
{t0, t1} = {4690.5`, 11110.5`};
dmmax = 0.0311949`;
plotbcg = 
  ListLinePlot[cdata, 
   PlotRange -> {{t0, t1}, {0, dmmax + 0.1*dmmax}}];

Format[σ[i_]] := Subscript[σ, i]
Format[a[i_]] := Subscript[a, i]
Format[μ[i_]] := Subscript[μ, i]
nd = Length@μd;
nu = 2;
ad2 = ConstantArray[0, nd + nu];
ad2[[;; nd]] = ad;
μd2 = ConstantArray[{t0, t0, t1}, nd + nu];
μΔ = 200;
μd2[[;; nd, 1]] = μd;
μd2[[;; nd, 2]] = μd - μΔ;
μd2[[;; nd, 3]] = μd + μΔ;
model3 = 
 Sum[a[i]*Exp[-((t - μ[i])^2/(2 σ[i]^2))], {i, 1, nd}] + 
  Sum[a[i]*Exp[-((t - μ[i])^2/(2 σ[i]^2))], {i, nd + 1, 
    nd + nu}]


With[
 {localmodel = 
   model3 /. ((({σ[#] -> σv[#], 
           a[#] -> av[#], μ[#] -> μv[#]}) & /@ 
        Range[nd + nu]) // Flatten)}, 
 data = Table[{av[i], μv[i], σv[i]}, {i, 1, nd + nu}];
 Manipulate[
  Show[
   Quiet@Plot[
     localmodel, {t, t0, t1},
     PlotStyle -> {Red},
     PlotRange -> {{t0, t1}, {0, dmmax + 0.1*dmmax}},
     PlotPoints -> 50,
     MaxRecursion -> 5
     ],
   plotbcg],
  Evaluate[
   Sequence @@ 
    Flatten[{{{σv[#], 50, Subscript[σ, #]}, 0.01, (
         t1 - t0)/10, 
         Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{av[#], ad2[[#]], 
          Subscript[a, #]}, 0, dmmax, 
         Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{μv[#], μd2[[#, 1]], 
          Subscript[μ, #]}, μd2[[#, 2]], μd2[[#, 3]], 
         Appearance -> "Labeled"}} & /@ Range[nd + nu], 1]
   ], Button["Get values", Print[data]]]]
```

This generates `Manipulate`:
[image]

The next steps are to obtain the model parameters and feed them as initial guesses to `NonlinearModelFit`.

Then I want to update the `Manipulate` variables with the fitted ones. But this is just to give pointers where I am heading with this. The idea is that you have data with peaks, some of them are determined with respect to the peak position and "height" and some are not determined at all but are necessary to get the fit. This is quite well illustrated by the data (note that I am using a gaussian to play with it but the peaks are not gaussian, but the exact model is not the point at the moment).

Comment: One thing you could do (referring to your update) is make `data` one of the "local variables" of the `With`. That will force the `Manipulate` to "see" those variables as "local" and associate them to the control variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that "Manipulate" has the attribute "HoldAll". If you calculate data outside of "Manipulate" it is evaluated fully:

```
plts = (mm[#]*Sin[x]) & /@ Range[5];
With[{localplot = plts /. {(mm[#] -> mv[#]) & /@ Range[5]} // Flatten,
   data = Table[mv[i], {i, 5}]}, 
 Manipulate[{Column[{Plot[localplot, {x, 0, 10}], 
     Button["Get values", Print[data]]}]}, 
  Evaluate[
   Sequence @@ ({{mv[#], 0, Subscript[a, #]}, 0, 1, 
        Appearance -> "Labeled"} & /@ Range[5])]]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. But in this case `data` will keep local scope within the `With` construct. Is there a way to assign the `mv` to a global variable?

Comment: Simply include "globaldat=data;" in the Manipulate;

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best way to do this. I'd like to more about your context, because maybe the whole setup can be improved. But generally, I avoid using non-atomic expressions as variables in Manipulate controls, so I'd be inclined to do something like this:

```
With[
  {plotCount = 5},
  With[
    {params = Symbol["a" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[plotCount]},
    With[
      {controls = {#, 0, 1} & /@ params},
      With[
        {plots = Sin[x] params},
        Manipulate[
          Plot[plots, {x, 0, 10}],
          Evaluate[Sequence @@ controls],
          Button["Print Values", Print[params]]]]]]]
```

Comment: I provided the full problem I am dealing with in the updated question. I want to visually best match the peaks, grab the parameters of the model and ultimately run a `NonlinearModelFit` to obtain the best fit.